# What is the reasoning behind marking a type that contains !Send fields with the Send trait?

Tags: rust

What is the reasoning behind marking a type that contains `!Send` fields (like `Rc` or `NonNull`) with the `Send` trait? For instance, the standard library's [`LinkedList`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/liballoc/collections/linked_list.rs) works in this fashion: it contains `Option<NonNull<_>>` fields and it implements `Send` trait (when `T` is `Send`).

How is this safe, what are the guarantees and ways to work safely with such a type?

Comment: There is a bit more about `Send` and `Sync` in the Nomicon: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/send-and-sync.html

Comment: @E_net4 yes but it states the following: "TODO: better explain what can or can't be Send or Sync. Sufficient to appeal only to data races?". My question seeking to find that explanation, what can or can't be Send or Sync, especially about complex types like LinkedList

Comment: For the particular case of `LinkedList`, it just had to be implemented in a way that ensures memory safety. Asking what can be `Send`/`Sync` in general is a much broader question.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the [rationale](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ptr.rs.html#2852) for `NonNull` being `!Send`:

> `NonNull` pointers are not `Send` because the data they reference **may** be aliased.

But the `NonNull` in `LinkedList` is a private implementation detail. If this type knows that the inner type `T` is `Send` and the usage it does is also `Send`-safe, (no unsafety in the public API) then it can reintroduce the `Send` trait.

That guarantee basically winds down to ensuring that you cannot get mutable aliases to the inner types; and ensuring that there is no unexpected inner mutability (get a mutable reference from an immutable one).

These guarantees are not given by `NonNull` but they are in `LinkedList`.

Comment: @rodrigo thanks for you answer, but

1. Isn't that something that compiler can help us with? e.g. checking that no refs to !Send types "flow" out of our type given the existing implementations?
2. Are there any good writeups on this in documentation or something? the Nomicon is actually not that helpful on the topic

Comment: @montekki: No, the compiler cannot know what you are doing or what the semantics are. For example, a type with internal mutability must not be `Sync` because several threads could modify it at the same time and cause a raze... unless it uses mutexes propery, in that case it is `Sync` safe again. But the proper use of mutexes cannot be inferred by the compiler.